# Svelte input number validation. I can't prevent the input of letters

Tags: javascript, svelte

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong. Letters are still being shown in the input.

```html
<script>
    let value = "";
    
    function isNumber(value) {
        return !isNaN(value);
    }

    function handleInput(e) {
        let oldValue = value;
        let newValue = e.target.value;

        console.log(oldValue, newValue, "isNumber", isNumber(newValue));

        if (isNumber(newValue) && newValue.length < 17) {
            value = newValue;
        } else {
            value = oldValue;
        }
    }
</script>

<div class="container">
    <input
        {value}
        on:input|preventDefault={handleInput}
    />
</div>
```

Here's the [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/21779f6db5314241ae568fc0b81b21be?version=3.43.0) as well.

Comment: I tried it, and it doesn't seem to work. [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/21779f6db5314241ae568fc0b81b21be?version=3.43.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could just do this:

```
else {
    e.target.value = oldValue;
}
```

Comment: Does this really work? Letters still show up.

Answer (score 1):

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/0b3057eed0b742b2b9e6dd669f29068b?version=3.52.0)

IF you want to warn the USER on input...
use below

```
<script>
  let value = "";


  // Check if user input is number  
  const onKeyPress = e => {
    if (!isFinite(e.key)) {
      alert('Not A number')
    }
  };

  $: value = value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')
</script>
<input bind:value on:keypress={onKeyPress} />
```

and without warning the user..
use below

```
<script>
  let value = "";

  $: value = value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')
</script>
<input bind:value />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me, taking inspiration from some of the other answers.

This:

- coerces the value to a number
- prevents any characters that make the value not result in a number
- have an extra `pattern` on the input to assist form submission

```js
export let value: number;

function updateValue(e: Event): void {
  const target = e.target as HTMLInputElement;
  const newValue = Number(target.value);

  if (!isNaN(newValue)) {
    value = newValue;
  } else {
    // reset to old value
    target.value = value.toString();
  }
}
```

```html
<input
  type="text"
  inputmode="numeric"
  pattern="[0-9.]*"
  {value}
  on:input|preventDefault={updateValue}
/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Set the input's type to "number".

```js
<input
    type='number'
    bind:value
    on:input|preventDefault={handleInput}
/>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/794a805ec8594559b93dd09bd45227a3?version=3.53.1)